# plot of an empirical cumulative distribution function (was Percentile plot) 

Tags: r

How can I generate a plot like the following in R.

[image]

It shows the percent of transactions (x) for a given response time (y), see my own answer below for my own go at it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Methinks you want a plot of an empirical cumulative distribution function.

So take a look at the documentation for `ecdf()` as well as the more featureful `Ecdf()` in the CRAN package [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc).

Hmisc Ecdf example: `ExecTm` array of execution times, 
`HttpProvCall` array of time it took to call downstream system and we compare the time we spend with the downstream system with percentiles

```
> library(Hmisc)
> x <- c(ExecTm,ExecTm-HttpProvCall)
> g <- c(rep('ExecTm',length(ExecTm)),rep('ExecTm-HttpProvCall',length(ExecTm)))
> Ecdf(x, group=g, xlab='Test Results', 
+     label.curves=list(keys=1:2),q=c(.90,.95,.98))
```

[image]

Comment: I just had a short look at the online help to `ecdf` to be sure and, whoops, there is the answer. On stackoverflow it pays to post first and think second if you want to gain points :) (btw +1)

Answer (score 0):

> y <- c(rnorm(8000, 300, 10), rnorm(400, 500, 300) )
>
> t2 <- quantile(y,  probs = seq(0, 99.99, by=.1)/100)
>
> plot(t2, xlab="promille ", ylab="time (ms)",pch=20)

gives me:

[image]

whit my dataset

[image]