# Plotting CDF of a dataset in R?

Tags: r, graph, plot, dataset

I am not really sure about the difference between CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) and ECDF (Empirical Cumulative Distribution Function) but I usually utilize a CDF plot to make observations about my data.

I have been using R recently and am desperately trying to find out how to plot a CDF and CCDF (Complementary CDF) of my data. All I could find was that R has ecdf but am not really sure if this is what I am looking for. Plotting an ECDF is as simple as:

```
plot.ecdf(data)
```

Does anyone know how to plot a CDF and CCDF of a dataset using R?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A CDF commonly requires closed form when you know or assume a distribution.  An ECDF, on the other hand, is 'empiricial' as it comes from your data.  I just answered a question about using `ecdf()` and [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc)'s `Ecdf()`   here [the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282655/plot-of-an-empirical-cumulative-distribution-function-was-percentile-plot).

More generally, you can search here using terms such as

```
 [r] ecdf
```

in the search box to look for 'ecdf' within the R tag.   At [rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org), little comes up for 'ccdf'. Is that maybe just the same as one minus the ECDF? If so, `Ecdf()` in Hmisc can do it.

I hope this helps, if not please re-phrase your question as it is not quite clear exactly what you are looking for. Both `ecdf()` and `Ecdf()` are pretty featureful so make sure to read their help pages.

Comment: +1 From your response in other posts, I realized you are an R Guru :) And yes, CCDF actually refers to 1-ECDF. Thank you for your response! I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Search for '1-F' in the Ecdf help page to find out how to calculate the CCDF from the Ecdf function.